# multiple joins to same sub query

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I need to join to the same table repeatedly but this looks ugly.  Any suggestions appreciated.  *Below is simplified SQL, I have 8 tables in the subquery and it produces many duplicate records of the same date, so I need to find only the newest record for each client.*  (I don't think DB and/or version should matter, but I am using DB2 11.1 LUW)

```
select c.client_num, a.eff_date, t.trx_date
from client c 
join address a on(a.id = c.addr_id)
join transaction t on(t.addr_id = a.id)
{many other joins}
where {many conditions};

select SQ.*
from [ABOVE_SUBQUERY] SQ
join
    (select client_num, max(eff_date) AS newest_date from [ABOVE_SUBQUERY] group by client_num) AA
    ON(SQ.client_num = AA.client_num and SQ.eff_date = AA.newest_date)
join
    (select client_num, max(trx_date) AS newest_date from [ABOVE_SUBQUERY] group by client_num) TT 
    ON(SQ.client_num = TT.client_num and SQ.trx_date = TT.newest_date)
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff, that worked well.  Accepted the answer, but it will not let me up-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to fine only the newest record for each client.

Can't you just use `row_number()`?

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by client_num order by eff_date desc, eff_time desc) as seqnum
      from <whatever> t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: An `APPLY` operation might also work, and if neither of those help a CTE is what directly answers the question.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I looked into Common Table Expressions (CTE) and that would more correctly answer my question.  But (as much as I don't like alternatives as answers) the row_number() recommendation eliminated my need for this.